# Error in SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
with [BlockedQueries] as 
(
   select 
      der.session_id, der.blocking_session_id, der.start_time, 
      der.total_elapsed_time,
      SUBSTRING(text, (statement_start_offset/2)+1,
      ((CASE statement_end_offset
             WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(text)
             ELSE statement_end_offset
         END - statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS sqltext
   from 
      sys.dm_exec_requests as der
   cross apply 
      sys.dm_exec_sql_text (der.sql_handle) as dest
   where 
      blocking_session_id <> 0

   union all

   select 
       c.session_id, c.blocking_session_id, c.start_time, c.total_elapsed_time, 
       dest.text 
   from
       [BlockedQueries] p, sys.dm_exec_requests as c
   cross apply 
       sys.dm_exec_sql_text (c.sql_handle) as dest
   where 
       p.[blocking_session_id] = c.[session_id]
)
```

When running this on SQL Server 2008, I get the following error.

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
>
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.*

I'm trying to run the one [in this link](https://cotega.com/docs/faq)
under Blocked Queries Agent.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Why does your second select in the union try to return rows from the CTE that it is part of?

Comment: @RowlandShaw - That is the syntax for a recursive CTE. Presumably this query traverses the chain of blocked queries. Haven't looked that closely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something after the with clause (and normally, a `;` before it)

```
   ;with blockedqueries as
   (
       ....
   )
   Select * from blockedqueries
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to this one by selecting from `Common Table Expression(CTE)`

```
with [BlockedQueries] as (

select der.session_id, der.blocking_session_id, der.start_time, der.total_elapsed_time,

SUBSTRING(text, (statement_start_offset/2)+1,

((CASE statement_end_offset

WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(text)

ELSE statement_end_offset

END - statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS sqltext

from sys.dm_exec_requests as der

cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (der.sql_handle) as dest

where blocking_session_id <> 0

union all

select c.session_id, c.blocking_session_id, c.start_time, c.total_elapsed_time, dest.text from

[BlockedQueries] p, sys.dm_exec_requests as c

cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (c.sql_handle) as dest

where p.[blocking_session_id] = c.[session_id]

)
SELECT * FROM [BlockedQueries];
```